# Counting unique columns but return the duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables where one maps the other two, my query returns a list of table(A)'s with multiple table(B)'s by referencing table(C).

my query

```
SELECT a.A_ID, a.DESC, b.B_ID, b.NAME, COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTAL
FROM table_A a
LEFT JOIN table_C c ON c.A_ID = a.A_ID
LEFT JOIN table_B b on b.B_ID = c.B_ID
```

table_A:

```
A_ID   |   DESC
10001  |   Sample
10002  |   Sample
10003  |   Sample
```

table_B:

```
B_ID   |   NAME
10001  |   Name 1
10002  |   Name 2
```

table_C:

```
C_ID   |   A_ID   |   B_ID
10001  |  10001   |  10001
10002  |  10001   |  10002
10003  |  10002   |  10001
```

The query returns the data i want, but my *total* counts the duplicates as well.

```
  |  A_ID  |  A_DESC  |  B_ID  |  B_NAME  | TOTAL  
1 | 10001  |  Sample  | 10001  |  Name_1  |   4
2 | 10001  |  Sample  | 10002  |  Name_2  |   4
3 | 10002  |  Sample  | 10001  |  Name_1  |   4
4 | 10003  |  Sample  | NULL   |  NULL    |   4
```

It counts the duplicates as well as I understand count just well.. counts. I'm having trouble with this since my scenario needs all of the data above but with the correct count *(without counting duplicates but returning the duplicates)*

Here is my desired return

```
  |  A_ID  |  A_DESC  |  B_ID  |  B_NAME  | TOTAL  
1 | 10001  |  Sample  | 10001  |  Name_1  |   3
2 | 10001  |  Sample  | 10002  |  Name_2  |   3
3 | 10002  |  Sample  | 10001  |  Name_1  |   3
4 | 10003  |  Sample  | NULL   |  NULL    |   3
```

I'm still new to sql and i've googled this with site:stackoverflow.com but most of the articles remove the duplicates.

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly how you are defining a duplicate, because all 4 rows are different, and all the columns have one value repeated in multiple rows... Is your desired result 3 because there are 3 unique values for `A_ID`, or is it 3 because there are 3 non-null records for `B_ID`?

Comment: Have you looked at any examples of `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`?

Comment: @GarethD sorry my bad, duplicates since there are only 3 unique values of A_ID

Comment: @TabAlleman i've tried distinct and i don't understand but it just gives me (1) as TOTAL and im using count(distinct a.A_ID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the equivalent of `COUNT(DISTINCT Col) OVER()` by using two `DENSE_RANK()` functions:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (A_ID INT, [Desc] VARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @B TABLE (B_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @C TABLE (C_ID INT, A_ID INT, B_ID INT);
INSERT @A VALUES (10001, 'Sample'), (10002, 'Sample'), (10003, 'Sample');
INSERT @B VALUES (10001, 'Name 1'), (10002, 'Name 2');
INSERT @C VALUES (10001, 10001, 10001), (10002, 10001, 10002), (10003, 10002, 10001);


SELECT a.A_ID, a.[DESC], b.B_ID, b.NAME, COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTAL,
        DenseRankAsc = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.A_ID ASC),
        DenseRankDesc = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.A_ID DESC),
        CountDistinct = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.A_ID ASC) 
                        + DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.A_ID DESC) - 1
FROM @A a
LEFT JOIN @C c ON c.A_ID = a.A_ID
LEFT JOIN @B b on b.B_ID = c.B_ID;
```

This gives

```
A_ID    DESC    B_ID    NAME        TOTAL   DenseRankAsc    DenseRankDesc   CountDistinct
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10003   Sample  NULL    NULL        4           3                   1           3
10002   Sample  10001   Name 1      4           2                   2           3
10001   Sample  10001   Name 1      4           1                   3           3
10001   Sample  10002   Name 2      4           1                   3           3
```

The premise is that by ordering both ascending and descending, you can identify the total number of unique items.

That being said, a much simpler solution is probably to do the count at a point when you know the results are distinct already, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (A_ID INT, [Desc] VARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @B TABLE (B_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @C TABLE (C_ID INT, A_ID INT, B_ID INT);
INSERT @A VALUES (10001, 'Sample'), (10002, 'Sample'), (10003, 'Sample');
INSERT @B VALUES (10001, 'Name 1'), (10002, 'Name 2');
INSERT @C VALUES (10001, 10001, 10001), (10002, 10001, 10002), (10003, 10002, 10001);


SELECT a.A_ID, a.[DESC], b.B_ID, b.NAME, a.TOTAL
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS Total FROM @A) a 
LEFT JOIN @C c ON c.A_ID = a.A_ID
LEFT JOIN @B b on b.B_ID = c.B_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed! Been scratching my head the whole day!